# Getting error on mapping project from TFS to my local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have just mapped a project from tfs to my local drive but when i am running this code it is showing this error : 
The view at `~/Views/Home/Index.aspx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>.`

can Anyone tell me Why i am getting this error.

Comment: I'm not sure the error is TFS related.....

Comment: Can you tell why i am getting this its coming when i run my project into my local machine

Comment: Well as a starter have you checked that Index.aspx does derive from one of the classes above?  Secondly, you say when you run the project on your local machine - does that imply it works elsewhere?

Comment: Check if all files are checked in on your other pc

Comment: @Andrew yes it is not working anywhere i also run it into tfs

Comment: Reference this ( http://forums.asp.net/t/1486431.aspx ) link !